# is there any downstream effects if we store the add to cart informationin in php cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I want to store cart data in php cookie instead of session. Is there any downstream effects if we store the add to cart information in cookie.

Any please give suggestions or instructions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be modified on client side so probably someone might hack into it and modify the data. You will have to take strict security measures. If you want to enforce security then you can't just rely on cookies